# Motivation for Uniform Cover definition of Uniform Space

Tags: general-topology, filters, uniform-spaces

The Uniform Cover definition of a Uniform Space is -

> A uniform space $(X,\Theta)$ is a set $X$ equipped with a distinguished family of uniform covers $\Theta$ from the set of coverings of $X$, forming a $\bf{filter}$ when ordered by $\bf {star\  refinement}$.

(I've added the bolded parts above)

What I wish to ask is $-$ why filter, and why star refinement? What is so special about these that provides sets in a cover the intuition of being of the 'same size'?

Comment: I suggest that in addition to putting those terms in bold, you also [supply definitions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the models for uniform spaces is the metric spaces, and typical uniform covers are $\mathcal{U}_r:=\{B(x,r)\mid : x \in X\}$ where $r>0$. One observation we can make is that $\mathcal{U}_r \prec_\ast \mathcal{U}_{3r}$ so that such covers are a filter base under $\prec_\ast$ (star refinement). We will also want to consider other covers "uniform", but only if they're refined by some $\mathcal{U}_r$, hence we get a filter rather naturally (upward closure).

It also makes sense when comparing to the entourage formulation of uniform spaces, where one of the axiosm is that every entourage $E$ has another entourage $D$ such that $D \circ D \subseteq E$ and we also get sort of refinements when we translate this to covers in the usual way.

Comment: Ok, I get why filters come naturally. But why do we consider star refinements, of all things? Why not just refinements? Or something stronger than star refinements?

Comment: @IshanDeo because of the fact that the different $r$-uniform covers are closed under star refinement (which is a pretty strong form of refinement).

Comment: That makes sense, but it still feels like you're retroactively justifying this.
For example. if you had to teach this topic in a class, how would you provide students with enough intuition such that the usage of star refinement seems natural?

Comment: @IshanDeo it works as a theory. It’s the theorems that it allows us to prove. The correspondences to other representations of uniform spaces. But it’s hard to justify a priori. Maybe if you first covered paracompactness or metrisabilon theorems, it’d be easier.

Comment: I have covered both. It still feels hard to justify a priori.